# .containsKey() method for c++ map

Tags: c++, templates

I want to save some repeating work and write a function that mimicks Java 
 .containsKey() method.

Basically I would like to have something like this:

```
 using namespace std;
 map<string,XYclass> mymap;
 if (!contains(mymap,"key as string") ) cout << "key not found" << endl;
```

In C++ one can check, if a map contains key in following way:

```
 m.find(str) != m.end();
```

I want to write a generic method that returns true if a key is contained in a map.

So far I have following:

```
template<typename A, typename B> inline bool contains(const std::map< A, B > m, const A& str)
{
    return m.find(str) != m.end();
}
```

which will fail to do template argument deduction, when I run it on a `map<string,int>` with following call `contains(mymap,"key as string")`, as "key as string" is actually a char array.

Function works fine when I do explicit instantiation (i.e. by using following call `contains<string,int>(mymap,"key as string")`)

How to do it properly?

Comment: why downvote? is it a bad practice?

Comment: make the template have 3 template arguments. Also please pass the std::map as reference, because otherwise you may have to go for coffee while it searches

Comment: MCVE or it didn't happen!

Comment: @smihael downvotes are likely because your question lacks a minimal example. Read about MCVEs in questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually you could use [`std::map::count`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/count/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One can exclude parameters from template argument deduction with the below identity trick:

```
template <typename T>
struct identity { typedef T type; };

template <typename A, typename B>
inline bool contains(const std::map<A, B>& m
                   , const typename identity<A>::type& str)
{
    return m.find(str) != m.end();
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/83ed49443112576c)

You don't need to specify type template arguments explicitly now.

---

To be precise, `std::map` has the total of *four* type template parameters:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename Cmp, typename Alloc>
inline bool contains(const std::map<A, B, Cmp, Alloc>& m
                   , const typename identity<A>::type& str);
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't hard-code it to `std::map`. The expression `c.find( k ) != c.end()` will work for any container with a `find` method returning an iterator. The function is applicable to any such types.

As others have noted, `std::map` has additional template parameters for the comparison function and the node allocator. In principle, listing all its parameters violates the separation of concerns.

```
template< typename container, typename key >
auto contains( container const & c, key const & k )
    -> decltype( c.find( k ) != c.end() )
    { return c.find( k ) != c.end(); }
```

The `decltype` specifier performs SFINAE, in case you want other overloads.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for declaring `contains()` function as template with 3 arguments:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value, typename Arg>
inline bool map_contains(const std::map< Key, Value > m, const Arg& value)
{
    return m.find(value) != m.end();
}
```

Note, that now `Arg` must be implicitly convertible to `Key`. You can easily remove this requirement - all you need to do is to call `find()` with `value` explicitly casted to `Key` type.

Live demo: [click](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7181d16c09ed1d7).